# python regex: looking for correct pattern with negative lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I am using python tool which checks git log commit messages to find out if feature with given ID was introduced or reverted. I cannot change the code of the tool. Can only provide proper regex as an input. Input looks like this:

```py
input_regexes = {
    "add_pattern": r".*\[\s*(ID\d{3})\s*\](.*)"
    "revert_pattern": r"[Rr]evert.*\[\s*(ID\d{3})\s*\](.*)"
}
```

First capture group is used to get feature ID and second is used as a feature description.
The problem is, when string with `[Rr]evert` appears, then both patterns match. What I would like to achieve is:

- `revert_pattern` pattern matches only commit messages which contain ID in brackets and preceding `[Rr]evert`
- `add_pattern` pattern matches only commit messages which contain ID in brackets and do not contain preceding `[Rr]evert`

In following example `revert_pattern` should match only `revert_feature_message` and `add_pattern` should match only strings available in `add_feature_messages`:

```py
revert_feature_message='Revert "[ID123] some cool feature."'
add_feature_messages=[
  '[ID123] some cool feature.',
  'some prefix [ID123] some cool feature'
]
```

I tried using:

```
(?<!Revert).*?\[\s*(ID\d{3})\s*\](.*)
```

as `add_pattern` but it didn't workout. Could you help make it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The revert pattern `[Rr]evert.*\[\s*(ID\d{3})\s*\](.*)` already matches only the `revert_feature_message`

To match only the strings in `add_feature_messages` you can assert that the string does not contain revert or Revert.

```
^(?!.*[Rr]evert).*\[\s*(ID\d{3})\s*\](.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tYdiFc/1)

Or a bit more specific:

```
^(?!.*[Rr]evert [^][]*\[\s*ID\d{3}\s*]).*\[\s*(ID\d{3})\s*\](.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SnsiUh/1)

If `Revert` is at the start of the string, you can omit the leading `.*`

Comment: wow, man, you actually did it! Could you please answer additional questions?

1. how did you manage to work "lookahead" as "lookbehind"? :D I thought "lookahead" construct is made for checking suffixes of the pattern

2. how is that possible "lookbehind" has to have fixed width and greedy dot is ok in "lookahead" construct ?

Comment: @marek_maras Glad it worked for you :-) The negative lookahead at the start asserts that the string does not contain first matching revert and after that the ID from the start of the string `^` So before the matching starts, this assertion runs once to verify this "rule". About the second question, using `re` does not support an infinite quantifier in the lookbehind. For that to work, you can use the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)